# Can I use a Forex card on booking.com?

Tags: international-travel, bookings, payment-cards, booking.com, forex-cards

I have a MasterCard based Forex multi-currency card issued in India.

Can I use this forex card for payment in Euros via booking.com online? Can I use the forex card the same way we use the credit cards? I do not see any information on the web regarding this.

Comment: Payment options differ from hotel to hotel. You may not be able to pay by card at all.

Comment: Not yet. I don't wanna know that it won't work after I have to travelled to Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Forex card website](https://indusforex.indusind.com/AMP/how-to-use-forex-card.html):

> **A Forex card can be used in the same way one uses debit and credit card.** When you are travelling abroad, you can use the Forex card to pay hotel bills, make purchases at various shops, restaurants and online sites. You simply need to enter your PIN or signature to complete the transaction.

Therefore, you would use your Forex Card the same way. There is no harm in trying to use it. Some hotels may reject it due to the fact that they require specific payment methods.

Comment: My question is, will auto debit work on these cards?

Comment: @sp497 yes it will